# How to use React's props.children for multiple nested components?

Tags: reactjs

I am building a small layout template using React Bootstrap components. The simplified structure will be:

```
<Layout
 <Header />
 <Sidebar />
 <Content />
 <Footer />
/>
```

When importing and using my component in an app, how will I be able "inject" some new React components inside the Sidebar, the Content, etc.?

I learnt about `props.children` [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) but got confused. I understood I cannot use this as is for my case, but should use it the way they describe in the SplitPane example ("Containment" section) instead.

However, I read many times that we should not pass components as props, and that's what they are doing.

Is this the way I should do it?

Comment: import other components in your component, like you imported in app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will inject children to those component just like in html:

```
<Layout
 <Header />
 <Sidebar />
 <Content >
    <SomeChildComponent/>
</Content>
 <Footer />
/>
```

Comment: For some reason, I thought that maybe I didn't want to export all my components, but I was overthinking...